# Condense a list of objects if a property on the object is the same

Tags: java

I have a list of objects that look like this:

```
public class MyObject {

  String id;
  List<String> list;

  MyObject(String id, List<String> list) {
    this.id = id;
    this.list = list;
  }

  String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  List<String> getList() {
    return list;
  }
}
```

I want to condense the list so that if two MyObjects have the same id, they are combined into one.

The best solution I could come up with is to override the equals method in MyObject so that 2 objects are equal if their ids are the same and do something like this:

```
List<MyObject> condense(List<MyObject> fullList) {
  List<MyObject> condensedList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (MyObject obj : fullList) {
    if (condensedList.contains(obj)) {
      MyObject obj2 = condensed.get(condensed.indexOf(obj));
      obj = merge(obj, obj2);
    }
    condensedList.add(obj);
  }
  return condensedList;
}

MyObject merge(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {
  List<String> merged = new ArrayList<>();
  merged.addAll(obj1.getList());
  merged.addAll(obj2.getList());
  return new MyObject(obj1.getId(), merged);
}
```

It's not a great solution because those objects aren't really equal if their ids are the same, they only need to be combined in this particular case. And it's not very concise. 
Is there a better way?

Comment: Two fors can solve it and you compare the getId from each object (and remember to skip if obj1 == obj2) and merge then without equals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed make this more concise.

```
List<MyObject> condense(List<MyObject> fullList) {
      Map<String, MyObject> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
      fullList.forEach(a -> tempMap.merge(a.getId(), a, MyObject::merge));
      return new ArrayList<>(tempMap.values());
}
```

This uses [Map::merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to perform the work.  [Map::merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) basically says if the specified key `a.getId()` is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value.

Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function `MyObject::merge`, or removes if the result is null.

Once that is done we collect the map values and return it into an `ArrayList` instance.

Note the `MyObject::merge` function above assumes `merge` is defined as   `public static MyObject merge (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {...}` within the `MyObject` class.

Answer (score 1):

Do use `Map` for collection objects:

```
public static List<MyObject> condense(List<MyObject> objs) {
    objs = Optional.ofNullable(objs).orElse(Collections.emptyList());

    Map<String, MyObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();   
    objs.stream().map(MyObject::getId).distinct().forEach(id -> map.put(id, new MyObject(id)));  
    objs.forEach(obj -> map.get(obj.getId()).addList(obj.getList()));

    return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```

**P.S.** Pay attention on `MyObject` incapsulation:

```
public final class MyObject {

    private final String id;
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyObject(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    public void addList(List<String> list) {
        this.list.addAll(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, without depending on the `equals` method.

```
List<MyObject> condense(List<MyObject> fullList) {
    // LinkedHashMap preserves the order of the original list
    // To make the result sorted by ID, use TreeMap instead
    Map<String, List<String>> lists = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (MyObject o : fullList) {
        List<String> list = lists.get(o.getId());
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>(o.getList());
            lists.put(o.getId(), list);
        } else {
            list.addAll(o.getList());
        }
    }

    List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>(lists.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : lists.entrySet()) {
        objects.add(new MyObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me. Only thing is I moved `lists.put(o.getId(), list)` outside of the if condition since we need to update the map for both conditions.

Comment: @KateBarett no there is no need to move it outside the if condition. If `list == null` returns false then the list is already in the map, and you do not need to put in the map again, just add to it.

Answer (score 1):

we can make use of Map's `merge()` method:

```
List<MyObject> condense(List<MyObject> fullList) {
    Map<String, MyObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    fullList.forEach(myObject -> {
        map.merge(myObject.getId(), myObject, (myObject1, myObject2) -> {
            myObject1.getList().addAll(myObject2.getList());
            return myObject1;
        });
    });
    return new ArrayList(map.values());
}
```

Note: null check was omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `merge` method is good, although I would initialize it with a size to prevent needless ArrayList resizing.

```
static MyObject merge (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {
    List<String> list1 = obj1.getList();
    List<String> list2 = obj2.getList();
    List<String> merged = new ArrayList<>(list1.size() + list2.size());
    merged.addAll(list1);
    merged.addAll(list2);
    return new MyObject(obj1.getId(), merged);
}
```

Next, stream your `List` into a `Map` so you can use a merge function to decide what to do when equal keys (your `id`) are encountered.  This will also be more efficient than searching the list for matching keys.

```
public List<MyObject> condense(List<MyObject> fullList) {
    Map<String, MyObject> temp = fullList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, Function.identity(), Main::merge));
    return new ArrayList<>(temp.values());
}
```

Here, you will use [the overload of `Collectors.toMap` that takes a key mapper, a value mapper, and a merge function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).  I've assumed that the class that `merge` is located in is `Main`.  Then you can convert the values back to a `List`.

Comment: @Downvoter How do you think this answer can be improved?